# Java SWT: Change colour of line when using GC.drawline

Tags: java, canvas, swt

If I am drawing a line using:

```
GC.drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
```

How do I change the colour of the line?

I can change the transparency by calling:

```
gc.setAlpha(150);
```

But I cannot find method of changing the colour of the line

Comment: Why was this voted down???????????????

Comment: Who knows, but one question mark would have been enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw functions draw with the foreground color:

```
gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
```

Comment: Great stuff @Enak  Thanks for your help